# Cannot set anything to stickynotification

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am starting stickynotification from my service using startForeground. Notification does show up however my settings, like title or intent to show up when clicked does not take effect.

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                                            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        //.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My Awesome App")
        .setContentText("Doing some work...")
        .setContentInfo("Server is running")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(1337, notification);
    super.onCreate();
}
```

Notification shows app name and touch for more info or to stop....

When clicked it takes me to app info where i can forestop or uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody out there in this universe having same problem i suggest do not overclock your brain else you will endup missing small things like requesting permissions.

Setting up icon fixed my issue.